# How to achieve result like textbox2 ,using VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, textbox

I have a regex that I use in vb.net, I want to output all eligible textbox1 line by line to textbox2, this is what I'm using.

```
 textbox1(Sorce)                    textbox2(Result)
  123kaadd234                             123,234
fjalj787fafkajl34ddfa999               787,134,999
```

My Code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pattern As String = "\d{3}"
        For row As Int16 = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            Dim input As String = TextBox1.Lines(row)
            Dim m As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
            For i As Int16 = 0 To m.Count - 1
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & m(i).ToString & "," & vbCrLf
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate code tags to improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the second line should result in `787,999` as there is no `1` before `34` (there is a letter `l`).

The rest of the code can be fixed using

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pattern As String = "\d{3}"
    For row As Int16 = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim input As String = TextBox1.Lines(row)
        Dim line As String = String.Join(",", Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList())
        TextBox2.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note:

- `Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()` collects all match values into a list
- `String.Join(",", ...)` joins the list into a single comma-separated string
- `TextBox2.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)` appends a new line to the multiline text box control.